# pyTelegramBotAPI: How to return value from function using states?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a problem with FSM using pyTelegramBotAPI.

I want to modify [code example from GitHub](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/custom_states.py) to return values (name, surname, age) from *ready_for_answer* function for further processing.

Usually, I would just call a function returning this values, but I can't figure out, how to do it using this code.

Here's how I imagine the code I want to get:

```
import telebot # telebot

from telebot import custom_filters
from telebot.handler_backends import State, StatesGroup #States

# States storage
from telebot.storage import StateMemoryStorage

# Now, you can pass storage to bot.
state_storage = StateMemoryStorage() # you can init here another storage

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN",
state_storage=state_storage)

# States group.
class MyStates(StatesGroup):
    # Just name variables differently
    name = State() # creating instances of State class is enough from now
    surname = State()
    age = State()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_ex(message):
    """
    Start command. Here we are starting state
    """
    bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, MyStates.name, message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi, write me a name')

# Any state
@bot.message_handler(state="*", commands=['cancel'])
def any_state(message):
    """
    Cancel state
    """
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Your state was cancelled.")
    bot.delete_state(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id)

@bot.message_handler(state=MyStates.name)
def name_get(message):
    """
    State 1. Will process when user's state is MyStates.name.
    """
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Now write me a surname')
    bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, MyStates.surname, message.chat.id)
    with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
 
@bot.message_handler(state=MyStates.surname)
def ask_age(message):
    """
    State 2. Will process when user's state is MyStates.surname.
    """
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "What is your age?")
    bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, MyStates.age, message.chat.id)
    with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
        data['surname'] = message.text
```

**I want to return name, surname and age from ready_for_answer function for further use in code**

```
# result
@bot.message_handler(state=MyStates.age, is_digit=True)
def ready_for_answer(message):
    """
    State 3. Will process when user's state is MyStates.age.
    """
    with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
        msg = ("Ready, take a look:\n<b>"
               f"Name: {data['name']}\n"
               f"Surname: {data['surname']}\n"
               f"Age: {message.text}</b>")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, parse_mode="html")
    bot.delete_state(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id)
```

**I want to return name, surname and age from ready_for_answer function for further use in code**

```
#incorrect number
@bot.message_handler(state=MyStates.age, is_digit=False)
def age_incorrect(message):
    """
    Wrong response for MyStates.age
    """
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Looks like you are submitting a string in the field age. Please enter a number')

# register filters

bot.add_custom_filter(custom_filters.StateFilter(bot))
bot.add_custom_filter(custom_filters.IsDigitFilter())

bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Tell me, please, how to do it right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can run function inside `ready_for_answer` and pass `data` to this function:

```
# result
@bot.message_handler(state=MyStates.age, is_digit=True)
def ready_for_answer(message):
    """
    State 3. Will process when user's state is MyStates.age.
    """
    with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
        msg = ("Ready, take a look:\n<b>"
               f"Name: {data['name']}\n"
               f"Surname: {data['surname']}\n"
               f"Age: {message.text}</b>")

        # here is this function
        func_to_use_next_in_code(data)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, parse_mode="html")
    bot.delete_state(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id)


def func_to_use_next_in_code(data):
    # do stuff..
    print(data)
```

Or you can save user data to any local storage and use it in another script.